# Remote to Remote Copy batch script?

Tags: script

I wrote a script that copies files from a remote workstation to a remote server, but I know ROBOCOPY and XCOPY first copies the files from the remote workstation to my workstation then to the server. Is there a way to have the file copied directly between the remote workstation and the server when I run the script on my station?

The only way I can think of is to PSexec to the remote workstation and copy to the server, looking to see if there was a another way to accomplish this.

Comment: Why not set the job at the "remote" workstation to kick off and run from there as a scheduled job to copy from there to the remote server, etc. with elevated permissions and bypass the need to do it from "your" workstation? Just run it from the location where the files are copied from to begin with and have it scheduled to run from there.

Comment: That was another option, but I have multiple sites and wanted to prevent needing a script for each site and make it centralized from HQ. Thank you.